# True property doesn't display the content

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working with Angular2 and I want to display a component only if a property is true.
When `sci` equals true it should display the `<sci-company-form>` but doesn't work !

If i set `public sci: boolean = true` or `public sci: boolean = false`   it works as expected.
I know it's a basic case but I can't find a solution it doesn't make sense to me.

component.html :

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="isSci($event.target.checked)">
<sci-company-form *ngIf="sci"></sci-company-form>
```

component.ts

```
public sci: boolean;

    isSci($event: boolean) {
        this.sci = $event;
        console.log("this.sci : " + this.sci + "$event :" + $event);
     }
```

Comment: does your console.log print true/false ? cause its weird it should be working

Comment: @yahyaelfakir  yes it does !

Comment: I would replace         `this.sci = $event;` with         `this.sci = !this.sci` :)

Comment: could you try to wrap your tag inside a div and put if condition on div. `<div *ngIf="sci"><sci-company-form></sci-company-form></div>`

Comment: But your code seems to work anyway: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vwkdvg. Check for css properties or something else than sci value or ngif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also you can do something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="x"/>

<hello *ngIf="x"></hello>
```

here is the [thing](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kxeorm?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: I updated the link using `ngIf` with component tag. Still is working without problems. Do you have any error on console?

Answer (score 1):

When you print $event, does it give the expected boolean value?

I think its better to have an initial value for that boolean when declared as a property, so that when ngIf is checked against that condition, before the event, it can work properly.

Answer (score 1):

try without **target**

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="isSci($event.checked)">
<sci-company-form *ngIf="sci"></sci-company-form>
```

Comment: I don't think it can work because checked is a property of target